Discrepancies Between .NET dotnet-dump Report and Docker Container Memory Usage
I have a .NET 6 WebAPI running as a Docker container. Recently, I've encountered an issue where the memory usage of this container continuously increases over time as it serves HTTP requests. Currently, the container's memory usage has reached 6GB. This API service primarily performs CRUD operations using EF Core.
Today, I tried running dotnet-dump collect -p <p_id> inside the container to collect a dump file. Surprisingly, the total size reported by dumpheap -stat is only around 300MB, which is significantly smaller compared to the 6GB memory usage reported by Docker (via docker stats). Below is the output of dumpheap -stat:

This is the output of docker stats command:

I checked /proc//smaps for any clues. What I found is that the report indicates a large amount of Anonymous Memory with significant sizes. Below is an example:

I would appreciate any suggestions or insights to help me determine what is consuming the memory.

how about using the command smem -r

The smem -r command reports that most of the RAM is consumed by the dotnet app.dll command. To get more details, I ran smem -m, which shows that the largest memory consumers are [heap] and . However, the size of [heap] is much smaller compared to . Any idea on the ?

You may need to track the undisposed resources to make sure they are disposed properly.

@QiangFu I also face the same issue, may I ask if you have any ways to track the undisposed resources?
